# gormでPreloadするときのテーブル名

Tags: go, gorm

```
db.Preload("Orders").Preload("Profile").Preload("Role").Find(&users)
//// SELECT * FROM users;
//// SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4); // has many
//// SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3,4); // has one
//// SELECT * FROM roles WHERE id IN (4,5,6); // belongs to
```

gormでPreloadを使うとき、上の例のように単数形でテーブル名を指定してもSQLでは複数形になります。(Profile -> profiles)
テーブル名を単数形で指定する方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: http://doc.gorm.io/models.html#conventions にある、`Table name is the pluralized version of struct name` が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: @metropolis ご指摘の通りにしたら無事テーブル名を設定することができました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

GORM はデフォルトだとテーブル名として必ず複数形を選ぶようになっています。強い理由が無いのであれば、この慣例にしたがうようにすると面倒が少ないです。

どうしてもこの挙動を変えたいのであれば、`Tabler` インターフェースを定義する必要があります。

```
func (Profile) TableName() string {
  return "profile"
}
```

ドキュメント：

- https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions
- https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Pluralized-Table-Name